# Can cat print variables inline from a text file? bash

Tags: bash, variables, cat

Using bash, I'm trying to print the entire text file, including values of variables inside a text file instead of the literal text ($var).

**txtfile.txt**

```
Here is some text. $var1 Here is some more. $var2
```

**using cat**

```
    cat txtfile.txt
```

prints

> Here is some text. $var1 Here is some more. $var2

How can I get it to expand the values of $var1 and $var2 in output ?

Comment: Where are those variables comes from? Arw those Bash variables? Or environment variables?

Comment: BinaryZebra pointed out an error I made in my answer, so I removed it.  There are inherently going to be security problems with anything that does this, since the file might contain the expression `$(run this command as you)`.

Comment: You could try `echo -e "$(cat file)" `

Comment: @Mahesh Kharvi No, that doesn't expand variables.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to perform variable expansion is when the shell parse a line.

That could be done only by making a var: a line to be processed by the shell.

That could be done with the command `eval`, or by calling `sh -c "$var"`.

This will do what you ask (This is a very insecure idea):

```
#!/bin/bash
var1="This is OnE var"
var2="This is var TwO"

while read -r line; do
   eval echo "$line"
done <txtfile.txt
```

With the file txtfile.txt containing:

```
this is var1=$var1 inside
the file, and var2=$var2.
```

The script above will output:

```
this is var1=This is OnE var inside
the file, and var2=This is var TwO.
```

Answer (score 0):

A safer way of doing this is to expand the variables you want to allow, yourself.  This doesn't run commands snuck into the file itself using shell substitutions, *e.g.* `$(chmod -R 777 ~ | true)`.

For example: `$(sed -r -e "s/\\\$var1\\b/$var1/g" -e "s/\\\$var2\\b/$var2/g" < file.txt)`.  You could also use `perl`.

Note that, in this example, you'd have to escape out any instances of the `/` delimiter within `$var1` or `$var2` themselves.